# Android: Same Images in table different size - ONLY when not debugging

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-studio

I am trying to display a table that has three rows. The first two are images, the third is just data.  I have tried to set them up with table row weights of 45%, 45%, 10%...  However that never happens, it always come out somewhere about 47%, 47%, 6%.

But that's minor compared to the behavior that I can't figure out.

The images and data come in async, so they are populated using a "runnable".
The problem is the first image gets bigger *every time it updates*.  And the second image keeps getting smaller.
However, here's the kicker, when I set breakpoints and pause it to debug it, it works exactly as I want it to.  It doesn't change sizes, the row heights do not change.

So, that said, here is my layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:id="@+id/mainscreen">
android:background="#00ff00"
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/img1box"
    android:layout_weight="45"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="image1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/img2box"
    android:layout_weight="45"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="image2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
</TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:id="@+id/dataholder"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/statusbox"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I have tried settings such as 0dp (or 0px), fill_parent, match_parent, wrap_content, and a dozen other configurations from web searches.

And the code snippets that happen when the data/images are posted (removed the parts that do stuff like findViewById(), that happens at onCreate() and works fine, plus rename some confidential variables):

```
 final Runnable HandleImage1Ready = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int height, width;
        float xfactor, yfactor;
        height = m_Image1Box.getHeight(); //  This is the TableRow
        width = m_Image1Box.getWidth();
    //  Compute the reduction factor, but it's 
    //   always by height right now, so we just use that
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(m_img1, 0, m_img1.length);
        yfactor = height / (float) image.getHeight();
        xfactor = width / (float) image.getWidth();
       //  create a new bitmap, I even try reducing the "height"
       //   to prevent the table row from growing...  doesn't help
        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, (int) (image.getWidth() * yfactor), height, true);
        m_Image1.setImageBitmap(scaled);
        CompleteProcessing();
    }

};

final Runnable HandleImage2Ready = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int height, width;
        float xfactor, yfactor;
        height = m_Image2Box.getHeight(); //  This is the TableRow
        width = m_Image2Box.getWidth();
       //  EVEN TRY USING THE SAME IMAGE ON ROW 2... 
        //Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(m_img2, 0, m_img2.length);
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(m_img1, 0, m_img1.length);
        yfactor = height / (float) image.getHeight();
        xfactor = width / (float) image.getWidth();
        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, (int) (image.getWidth() * yfactor), height, true);
        m_Image2.setImageBitmap(scaled);
        CompleteProcessing();
    }
};
final Runnable HandleMicrReady = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int height, width;
     //  Just to debug these, and see how this row changes 
        height = m_statusBox.getHeight();
        width = m_statusBox.getWidth();
        m_statusBox.setText(m_data);
        CompleteProcessing();
    }
};
```

Repeating...  When I set a break point in one of the above functions, and resume the execution, both images are the same size, every time it posts new images.  Which is what I want to happen.

But if I don't set the break point, every time a new image is posted, the top table row gets bigger and bigger.  To the point that the top image is over 50% of the table (screen), and the bottom image and table row of data are getting smaller.

In essence, I believe Android Studio is laughing at me because, like a rattle in a car you take in, it doesn't do it when someone is watching for the problem...

(I included an "android-studio" tag, because pausing it in AS debugger causes the problem it disappear).

Any advice is appreciated.

-Scotty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table layouts do not seem to take the weights placed upon them very strictly. E.g. when you add an `ImageView` to a `TableRow` with or without a `src` it already renders slightly differently. I also verified this with 2 images with different dimensions and the row with the bigger image completely overtakes the row of the smaller one.

The solution is to not use a `TableLayout`. If you don't want to use something like a `GridView` I suggest sticking with `LinearLayout`. You can use it in the exact same manner. You only need to specify its `android:orientation="horizontal|vertical"` attribute instead of making a distinction between `TableRow` (the horizontal kind) or `TableLayout` (the vertical kind)

Here's a visual comparison:

[image]

So for your provided layout XML this would become:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:weightSum="100"
android:background="#00ff00"
android:id="@+id/mainscreen">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/img1box"
    android:layout_weight="45"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="image1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/img2box"
    android:layout_weight="45"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="image2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />
</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:id="@+id/dataholder"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/statusbox"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This worked well.  And it also eliminated the need to scale the bitmap.  The image apparently is automatically adjusting to the height of the LinearLayout ID.  Thanks.